# is it efficient way to store data in Database?

Tags: database

I got a job in a small company.
I'm renewing existing project.

In the database, all the data are contained in JSON formmat.
It looks like this.

```
{"app_ip":"192.168.1.36","app_edate":"1319690682","app_region":"English","app_uuid":"c404a51da152938861ffb215550425cb6f8c12bd","app_id":"com.byto.neokhan","app_ip_3g":"10.169.244.113","app_platform":"iPhone","app_sdate":"1319690542","app_osinfo":"iPhone OS 4.3.5","app_ver":"1.2"}
```

I believe this is somehow not good way to store data.
I just want to know if this is not a problem or not.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If all the data is used together, it makes it easy to extract once and use it.

However, one of the pros about databases is sorting it and stuff - if you split it up into tables and columns, you could easily find the number of people on the iPhone client. Or look up an ID. Often you would want these things so in that case yes - it is not making effective use of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in this format will kill the purpose of using Database. Database "is an organized collection of data". So your answer is right here in the definition of the Database. As @Raeki told you should use proper Tables.